# unable to connect websocket(wss) from c#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome-extension, websocket

In my application I am connecting chrome extension with windows application using websocket, 
Javascript code :

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://172.xx.xxx.xx:11223/');
socket.onopen = function(event)
{
    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
    socket.send("hi..");
};
```

And C# code :

```
public static TcpListener Weblistener = null;
public static int selWebSocketPort = 0;
public static void StartListeningSahi()
{
    Weblistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddStr), portNumForSelenium);
    try{
        Weblistener.Start();
        int TestingCycle = 100;
        // Start listening for connections.
        while (TestingCycle > 0){
            TcpClient handler = Weblistener.AcceptTcpClient();
            // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
            lock (ClientSockets.SyncRoot){
                if (handler != null){
                    int i = ClientSockets.Add(new ClientHandler(handler));
                    ((ClientHandler)ClientSockets[i]).Start();
                    SelWebSocketPort = (handler.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Port;
                    NetworkStream networkStream = handler.GetStream();
                    Byte[] clientReq = new Byte[handler.Available];
                    networkStream.Read(clientReq, 0, clientReq.Length);
                    string headerRequest = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(clientReq);
                    SendResponseToWebSocket(handler, networkStream, headerRequest);
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        Weblistener.Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static void SendResponseToWebSocket(TcpClient handler, NetworkStream networkStream, string headerRequest)
{
    // generate accept key fromm client header request
    var key = headerRequest.Replace("ey:", "`")
                     .Split('`')[1]                     
                     .Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0]  
                     .Trim();
    var responseKey = AcceptKey(ref key);
    //create the response for the webclient
    var newLine = "\r\n";
    var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                 + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                 + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine
                 + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + responseKey + newLine + newLine;
    //send respose to the webclient
    Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
    networkStream.Flush();

    selWebSocketPort = (handler.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Port;
}
```

This is working fine for `http` site. But after that I changed the this javascript line `var socket = new WebSocket('ws://172.xx.xxx.xx:11223/');` to `var socket = new WebSocket('wss://172.xx.xxx.xx:11223/');` to support `https` sites, but unable to do so. I am getting below error on chrome  -

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://172.16.106.22:11223/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

The handshaking is getting failed as in the request header I am getting some junk value.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Just use existing C# websocket library instead of (incorrectly) reimplementing it yourself with TcpListener.

Comment: The moment I see `.Available` being used for **anything** except deciding whether to read sync or async - but *especially* when deciding "that's the chunk I can definitely process as a single unit": I can conclude that this is probably doomed and is probably only working by chance right now; it is *not known* that you have a whole frame, or exactly one frame, at that point. However, you code appears to have **no** TLS code; if you're connecting to `wss://`, your server needs to implement TLS server. Which is a lot of work, and is not going to be very compatible with your existing code...

Comment: did you solve the problem?